# Nodetool operations on a remote Cassandra node

Tags: cassandra, nodetool

I'm creating a script to invoke nodetool operations such as 'nodetool repair' on a given remote Cassandra node. I can do this by performing the command via ssh, but I was wondering if there is a better way, e.g. is there some web (rest?) interface that I don't know about?

Thank you for your attention

Answer (score 1):

You can use nodetool on remote host the following way:

```
nodetool -h <ipaddress> repair
```

Comment: the machine from which I will execute the script does not have a Cassandra (hence nodetool) installation, any suggestions?

Comment: Maybe you could export just the `nodetool` from your Cassandra insallation. https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/68332/how-can-i-get-nodetool-without-cassandra

Comment: or you can run using ssh: ssh user1@server1 'nodetool <command>'

Comment: @Horia - Yes, that's also a viable option. And you don't have to bother with packing / unpacking and updating your nodetool.

Comment: @Horia, I realise that is a viable option but as I mentioned in the question that is exactly what I'm trying to avoid

Comment: @JoãoMatos - In this case you could create a java client that would fire it through JMX.

Comment: @Horia yes, I'm trying it now

Comment: If a JMX client in Java is too much effort, you can still try to export the nodetool as a separate package.

Comment: @JoãoMatos - why SSH is not an option, by the way?

Comment: @Oresztesz It is an option, I just don't like it

Answer (score 0):

Basically, what nodetool does when you run repair is to start it via JMX. You can do the same.

Comment: how...please specify?